# Migrations de relações ManyToMany no TypeORM usando QueryRunner

Tags: javascript, typescript, migrations, typeorm

É possível criar o SQL de uma migration automáticamente, através da CLI com o comando `migration:generate -n MigrationName`?

Entretanto, é possível criar migrations atavés da [migration API](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations/using-migration-api-to-write-migrations), de forma mais legível que SQL puro.

### Exemplo

**Entidades**

```
@Entity('students')
class Student {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
   id: string;

   @Column()
   name: string;
}
```

---

```
@Entity('classes')
class Class {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
   id: string

   @Column()
   name: string;
   
   @ManyToMany(() => Student)
   @JoinTable()
   students: Student[];
}
```

---

O problema está na criação de relacionamentos ManyToMany com a [migration API](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations/using-migration-api-to-write-migrations), que não está descrita na documentação.

**Migration de *Class* usando [migration API](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations/using-migration-api-to-write-migrations), sem o relacionamento ManyToMany**

```
export class CreateClass implements MigrationInterface {

    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: 'classes',
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'uuid',
                    isPrimary: true,
                    generationStrategy: 'uuid',
                    default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
                },
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'varchar'
                }
            ],
        }))
    }
}
```

#### Como criar essa migration com o relacionamento ManyToMany, usando o QueryRunner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Criando as tabelas do relacionamento

A melhor maneira de criar essa relação é descrevendo a tabela intermediária da relação ManyToMany, usando o **QueryRunner**.


É importante prestar a atenção nas **nomenclaturas** da tabela e dos campos, para que sejam compatíveis com o que o TypeORM geraria em **SQL**.


Portanto, bastaria adicionar a tabela do relacionamento **ManyToMany**, *depois* da criação da tabela descrita no exemplo da pergunta.

```
await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
    name: 'classes_students_students',
    columns: [
        {
             name: 'classesId',
             type: 'uuid',
             isPrimary: true,
        },
        {
             name: 'studentsId',
             type: 'uuid',
             isPrimary: true,
        },
    ],
    foreignKeys: [
        {
            columnNames: ['classesId'],
            referencedColumnNames: ['id'],
            referencedTableName: 'classes',
        },
        {
            columnNames: ['studentsId'],
            referencedColumnNames: ['id'],
            referencedTableName: 'students',
        },
    ],
}))
```

#### Nomenclaturas

**Tabelas**


A tabela do relacionamento precisa seguir a seguinte fórmula *nomeDaTabelaOriginal_nomeDoCampoManyToManyDaEntity_nomeDaOutraTabela*

**Campos**


Os campos que vão relacionar as tabelas é mais simples: *nomeDaTabelaReferenciada***Id**